# Tkinter - Trigger an event when two Entry Widgets are written into,regardless of order

Tags: python, events, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I just started **Tkinter** a week ago and I am trying to link the GUI to an automatic code generation script written in **Python**. I have covered almost all cases with great help from this forum but this particular one has me stumped.

I need 2 Entry Widgets and calculate their relationship to each other as soon as they are entered (i.e. no Button widget to trigger a function). I realize it must be done with events so after some trying I have come up with the following that works but it feels like I am not being 'pythonic' about it.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")

def OnValidate(S):
    if S.isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def insert_text_widg(widg,msg):
    widg.delete(1.0,END)
    widg.insert(INSERT,msg)

# Checks the required conditions
def check_var1(event):
    try:
        temp1=int(var1_ent.get())
        temp2=int(var2_ent.get())
    except ValueError:
        return
    if(temp2 > temp1):
        insert_text_widg(log_text,"ERROR: Var2 cannot be greater than Var1")
        for ent in [var1_ent,var2_ent]:
            ent.configure(bg='indian red',fg='white')
    elif ((temp1 - temp2) % 2) == 1:
        insert_text_widg(log_text,"ERROR: Difference cannot be odd")
        for ent in [var1_ent,var2_ent]:
            ent.configure(bg='indian red',fg='white')
    else:
        log_text.delete(1.0,END)
        for ent in [var1_ent,var2_ent]:
            ent.configure(bg='white',fg='black')

# Duplicate of check_var1
def check_var2(event):
    try:
        temp2=int(var2_ent.get())
        temp1=int(var1_ent.get())
    except ValueError:
        return
    if(temp2 > temp1):
        for ent in [var1_ent,var2_ent]:
            ent.configure(bg='indian red',fg='white')
        insert_text_widg(log_text,"ERROR: Var2 cannot be greater than Var1")
    elif ((temp1 - temp2) % 2) == 1:
        for ent in [var1_ent,var2_ent]:
            ent.configure(bg='indian red',fg='white')
        insert_text_widg(log_text,"ERROR: Difference cannot be odd")
    else:
        log_text.delete(1.0,END)
        for ent in [var1_ent,var2_ent]:
            ent.configure(bg='white',fg='black')


# App Configuration
vcmd = (root.register(OnValidate),'%S')

var1_lab = Label(root,text='Var1 :')
var1_lab.pack()

var1_ent = Entry(root,validate="key",validatecommand=vcmd)
var1_ent.bind("<KeyRelease>",check_var1)
var1_ent.pack()

var2_lab = Label(root,text='Var2 :')
var2_lab.pack()

var2_ent = Entry(root,validate="key",validatecommand=vcmd)
var2_ent.bind("<KeyRelease>",check_var2)
var2_ent.pack()

log_text = Text(root)
log_text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

There are two functions(**check_var1() & check_var2()**) which essentially do the same thing that I am looking to merge into one.
The checks need to be performed as soon as any of the Entry widgets register a change.

So in short,I would like a way to call the **check_var1()** function as soon as either Entry widget is typed in,regardless of the order of they are typed in.

Any help or a nudge in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you use:
var2_ent.bind("<KeyRelease>",check_var1) ???

Comment: The main problem is the order in which the user enters the input. I tried your suggestion,but the exception is caught if the user enters Var2 first when Var1 is empty and returns. Maybe I am handling the exception wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you need correctly then it sounds to me like you'd be best off using the `.trace()` function.

This allows you to raise a callback whenever a variable is written to or read.

In this case we'd create two variables `var1` and `var2` (for simplicity's sake) and assign these the value of `StringVar()`.

We'd then set the attribute `textvariable` of each `Entry` widgets to be `var1` and `var2` respectively.

We then need to set up the `.trace()` itself, so we call `var1.trace("w", callback)` and `var2.trace("w", callback)` (where the `"w"` means write) which runs the callback function every time either variable is written to.

This means that no matter which `Entry` is modified first, we get a callback and more importantly we get a callback for every modification.

See below for a working example:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.var1 = StringVar()
        self.var2 = StringVar()
        self.var1.trace("w", self.callback)
        self.var2.trace("w", self.callback)
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.root, text="Ok", textvariable=self.var1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.root, text="Ok", textvariable=self.var2)
        self.label = Label(self.root)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.label.pack()
    def callback(self, *args):
        self.label.configure(text=self.entry1.get()+self.entry2.get())

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```